# Checking text in file comparing it to user input

Tags: java

This is where it asks the user to input their information then run checkID();
to compare already existing ID's in the file to the user input

```
public static void newRecord()
{
    System.out.println("Enter your full name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();
    name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your age: " );
    age = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your id: ");
    id = input.nextInt();

    checkID();



    if(checkID())
    {
        start();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(id);
        addRecords();
    }
}
```

This is where i check the ID's. I check where ID: starts and then look for the value of id, but it doesn't detect the ID in the file and it creates the exact Id rather than telling the user the id has already been taken

```
public static boolean checkID()
{
    Scanner y = new Scanner("Names.txt");
    while(y.hasNextLine())
    {
        final String idChecker = y.nextLine();
        if(idChecker.startsWith("ID: ") && idChecker.substring(4).equals(String.valueOf(id)))
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, this ID has already been taken, please try again.");
            y.close();
            return true;
        }
    }
    y.close();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: It doens't say Sorry this Id has already been taken, please try again, when i have an already existing id when i try to enter the same one

Comment: I was mistaken the problem, you need to give us the code of start() and addRecords() method. If I am not mistaken in the start() method you may call checkID() method.

Comment: Given your file format, you can't make a search over all the lines. What if you wanted to create a user with ID 43? It will fail just because there's a Jimmy that old although his ID is 3333.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to pass a `File` object to your `Scanner` instead of the file name.
2. The other issue is that you should only call `addRecords()` once you've checked all the ids in *Names.txt* i.e. once your `while` loop exits without going into the `if` block.
3. You should also use `equals()` instead of `contains()` because otherwise you can't create an id `11` if `1` already exists!

Your `checkID()` method should ideally return a `boolean` indicating an already existing id and the caller should then call `start()` or `addRecords()` accordingly.

```
public static boolean checkID()
{
    try {
        Scanner y = new Scanner(new File("Names.txt")); // pass File instance
        while(y.hasNextLine())
        {
            final String idChecker = y.nextLine();
            if(idChecker.startsWith("ID: ") &&
               idChecker.substring(4).equals(String.valueOf(id)))
            {
                System.out.println(
                    "Sorry, this ID has already been taken, please try again.");
                y.close();
                return true;
            }
        }
        y.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that I'm calling `Scanner#close()` when done. Your `newRecord()` method should look something like

```
public static void newRecord()
{
    System.out.println("Enter your full name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your age: " );
    age = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter your id: ");
    id = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println(id);

    if(checkID())
    {
      start();
    }
    else
    {
        addRecords();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the if statement go?

Comment: What does your names.txt look like? Edit your question and add a snippet there.

Comment: Hmm, well I just edited my answer to include why you can't use contains(). Given your current file format you'll need to extract the id string from the ID: line and do an equals comparison. The reason is that otherwise you can't create a user with ID 33 if ID 3333 already exists!

Comment: Thanks, ill give it a try

Comment: Updated the code to extract the ID for comparison. It should work now. Just make sure `id` has the correct value. Log it with System.out.println().

Comment: Where does the if statement go?

Comment: At the place where you're currently calling checkID() from.

Comment: Still doesn't detect that it has the same id in the file

Comment: Updated the answer. You need to pass a `File` object to `Scanner`. Just the file name doesn't work. Also, there are some redundant `nextLine()` calls that you can do away with.